# Get Site Page URL (Modern Experience) - Pnpjs v1

Tags: sharepoint-online, sitepages, pnpjs

I have a team site where the pages will be used to create a wiki for a company. In the image you can see the pages of the site created for the moment. I have added an **MMS** column for *Managed Metadata Service*. MMS is used to assign to a page a *term* in a previously created *termset*.

**What I want to do**

Modify the local properties of the term to give it the address of the page to which it is assigned, so I need to retrieve the **URL** that leads to each page of the site.

[image]

I have this code, where I retrieve Title of each page, but URL of pages in modern experience does not depend on the Title:

```
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Site Pages").items.select("Title, MMS").getAll().then((resp: Imms[])=> {
      resp.forEach(async element => {
        if(element["MMS"] != null ) {
          termGuidTab.push(element["MMS"]["TermGuid"]);
          termGuid = element["MMS"]["TermGuid"];
          termTitle = element["Title"]; 
        }
      }
}
```

So, how can I get URL of each page from Site Pages?

Comment: What identifying information do you have that want to use to get a page's URL?  Normally you would use the URL to obtain a reference to the page.  Do you have a page reference already, or a library name and page name, or looping through library contents, etc?  What is your starting point from which you need to find the URL?

Comment: Do you want to get the home page of the site or Site Pages Library URL?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Try using `.select("Title", "FileRef", "MMS")`. This will give you a relative URL of the Site Page like `sites/SiteName/SitePages/PageName.aspx`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for.